# jQuery: finding the triggering element for a bubbling event in a parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following chunk of HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <button 
                class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
                type="button" 
                data-toggle="dropdown" 
                aria-haspopup="true" 
                aria-expanded="false">&pound;</button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <span class="dropdown-item" data-value="£">&pound;</span>
                <span class="dropdown-item" data-value="%">%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="new_item_value_type[]" value="£">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-right" name="new_item_value[]">
    </div>
</div>
```

This HTML is generated dynamically and added to a `<div>` with a class of `item-list`.

I have the following Javascript:

```
$('.item-list').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    console.log('dropdown hide event', $this);
});
```

This captures the `dropdown hide event`, however it does not tell me which element triggered that event. The variable `$this` relates to the parent element and not the triggering element.

How can I tell which element triggered this event when I am listening for this event to bubble up to a parent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events):

> All dropdown events are fired at the `.dropdown-menu`’s parent element and have a `relatedTarget` property, whose value is the toggling anchor element.

A such you code can be changed to this:

```
$('.item-list').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  console.log('dropdown hide event', e.relatedTarget);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) - Try this in your code

```js
$('.item-list').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
  // var $this = $(this);
  // console.log('dropdown hide event', $this);
  console.log('element clicked', e.target)
});
```

Comment: It's `relatedTarget` when dealing with event raised by a Bootstrap component: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/#events

Answer (score 1):

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

```
function getTarget(e)
 {
        var e = e || window.event, t;

        if (e.target) t = e.target;
        else if (e.srcElement) t = e.srcElement;

        if (t.nodeType == 3) // defeat Safari bug
         t = t.parentNode;

        return t;
 }
```